# Newly created authoring resource not showing up in Luis portal

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I added an authoring resource in the Luis Portal and imported a few apps. The added authoring resource appeared both in the Azure portal and the Luis portal initially. Then suddenly the resource disappeared in the Luis portal and now I am unable to select the resource using the drop down in the Apps page as it is no longer showing in there. (screenshot below) What is going on? The resource still shows up in the Azure portal. I tried logging out and in and refreshing the page multiple times.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see the resource in LUIS > Manage > Azure Resources? How quickly did you import apps after creating the resource? Migration takes awhile on the backend and that may have caused issues. In LUIS, click on "Manage" in the top bar then under "Application Settings" > "Azure Resources" unassign any resources listed, then try the migration again. Can you also sign out of LUIS, clear cache and cookies, then see if that resolves this? Try the [troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-authoring#troubleshooting)

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT. Thanks for the response. I still do not see the resource in the LUIS portal anywhere. I know the resource is there as I see them in the azure portal and can make REST calls to it. Unfortunately, signing out/clearing cache don't seem to solve it. I created these resources in the LUIS portal, they shows up in the azure portal immediately after and still do so I am not sure if it's a migration (to Azure) issue.

Comment: You've tried re-migrating and following the troubleshooting steps? Note that LUIS is having some issues currently, so today may not be the best time to try fixing this.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, how to I re-migrate? I can't find any link in the Luis portal to force migrate. FYI, I tried creating the resource two different ways. a. tried creating the resource in the portal. b. tried creating the resource in the Azure portal. In both cases, the resource show up in the Azure portal, but not in the Luis portal. From the doc, it appears that migration is so that you can give control accesses in the azure portal. I can already do that as the resource show up in the Azure portal.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your message. You're the owner of those LUIS apps, right? Not just a collaborator? If so, it seems something may have gone wrong with your LUIS account. It's a pain, I know, but I'd recommend exporting all of your LUIS apps, deleting all of your LUIS Azure resources, deleting your LUIS account, then re-creating your LUIS account.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, thanks! I actually filed a support ticket on this and other issues with REST endpoint and was notified that the service team identified the cause. I will wait and provide an update on that here.

Comment: Hello everyone. I am new to azure and am trying to create a LUIS app. But I don't know what they mean when they ask for an "Authoring resource". I imagine it's something created in the azure portal but is it a bot service, a resource group... ?? I'm stuck and lost, I would appreciate any help!! thanks!! (for info my drop down menu is blank)

Comment: @CealClem, it's a Azure resource. Go to azure portal, create resource and type in "Language Understanding" from there you can create the resource.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this issue myself in the past - the solution was to make sure you are using the correct LUIS portal that matches the data centre you deployed your LUIS resources in:

- westus: https://www.luis.ai/
- westeurope: https://eu.luis.ai/
- australiaeast: https://au.luis.ai/

This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions