# Unable to assign LUIS az accounts to LUIS apps via REST

Tags: azure-language-understanding

The luis resources that I created aren't showing up in the Luis portal ([posted a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729721/newly-created-authoring-resource-not-showing-up-in-luis-portal)) so decided to use the [REST APIs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32028a1d48f88cfd57e20) to configure things manually. With the REST endpoints I was able to import apps. However, I wasn't able to add LU resource to the imported apps despite that the APIs return success.

Below is the call.

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/<appid>/azureaccounts
```

```
{
    "azureSubscriptionId": "<id>",
    "resourceGroup": "<rg name>",
    "accountName": "<resource name>"
}
```

returns 201 CREATED

```
{
    "code": "Success",
    "message": "Operation Successful"
}
```

However, a subsequent GET call returns empty result.

```
GET https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/<appid>/azureaccounts
```

tried the GET call a couple hours after and it is still returning empty result. What is going on?

Comment: Hi Nate. There have been some LUIS hiccups this weekend. Can you try this again this morning, and let me know if you're still experiencing the same issue?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes, thanks for the response. Unfortunately the query still isn't working; it returns success even though account isn't added. I feel that the request should have failed if there was an issue in the backend. Is there a website or distribution list to be notified when there an issue with the service?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's something wrong with your azure account and/or your luis.ai account. There are two places to raise support requests to handle these types of matters. First is uservoice on LUIS.ai:

[image: feeback request on LUIS.ai site]

While issues raised here are typically routed back to the bot framework support team, once there, they can be escalated.

Secondly, you can raise the issue in Azure:

[image: azure support requests]

You can follow this link [HERE](https://portal.azure.com/?quickstart=true#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) to get to that blade quickly.

Comment: Thanks! I raised the issue in Azure.